# Why is my .travis.yml file being ignored?

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

Here is my **.travis.yml** file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.10"
  - "6"
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
```

(It is also [available on Github](https://github.com/ladenedge/t3services/blob/master/.travis.yml).)

Here is my build log on Travis, showing the wrong Node version:

> [image: Travis build log]

And here is the versionless config for the same build:

> [image]

Finally, here is the caching report for my build:

> [image]

I have tried changing my **.travis.yml** file in numerous ways, including:

- other version strings,
- different indentations and line ending combinations,
- with and without `cache`, etc.,

but nothing I do seems to have any effect.

I have enabled "Build only if .travis.yml is present", so apparently it is finding the file itself, just not what's in it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was hidden leading whitespace before my **language** key.  A helpful Travis tech support specialist [removed the whitespace](https://github.com/ladenedge/smartcare/commit/306ee1de8b9ab490a11de579010e246c4dda28a3) and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution was, that I had a foder named `.travis/` in the root directory. I had to rename it to something else and then travis notived the `.travis.yml` file again